# Зависит ли речь от пола/возраста/воспитания?

Tags: недопустимая-метка

Читала исследования когда-то, что речь зависит от соцдем характеристик. Но теперь не могу найти статьи на эту тему, кто-нибудь может подсказать?

Интересует, какие именно характеристики влияют на речь:

- мужская/женская речь
- речь людей разных возрастов (я не знаю, насоклько дробно делить)
- речь людей с разным образованием,
  Касается ли это только устной или письменной речи (или и той, и той)?

и какие особенности речи можно контролировать сознательно (например, человек может материться с друзьями, но никогда не с родителями или с клиентами на работе), а какие мы выбираем неосознанно (например, выбор агентивных-безагенсных конструкций, согласно теории М.В. Новиковой-Грунд)? 
Большое спасибо.

Comment: Характеристики... влияют на речь русскую? Даже, если только так, то вопрос слишком не конкретен.

Comment: Как я могу его уточнить? Вопрос про русскую речь. Характеристики влияют = отличается ли мужская речь от женской, людей подросткового возраста от речи взрослых людей и тп. Интересуют именно исследования по этой теме

Comment: Нажав на кнопку Править.

Comment: [Каковы отличительные характеристики мужской и женской речи?](https://youtu.be/w94Ndkw-rA8)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Работ по лингвистике, посвященных изучению особенностей речи языковой личности, зависящих от гендерных, профессиональных, психологических и др. характеристик очень много. Безусловно, заявленные характеристики (по отдельности и в совокупности) влияют как на устную, так и на письменную речь.

Вот некоторые исследования, посвященные заявленной Вами проблеме.

Гиль О.Г. Устная речь как источник информации о личности // http://frgf.utmn.ru/last/No5/text7.htm

Пентегова О.Ю. Влияние темперамента человека на его речь

Кирилина А., Томская М. Лингвистичсекие гендерные исследования

Аниськина, Н. В. Языковая личность современного старшеклассника: дис. ... канд. филол. наук. – Ярославль, 2001.

Валиулина, В. Р. Анализ психологического аспекта речевой деятельности испытуемых с разными типами характера // Вестн. РУДН. Сер.: Психология и педагогика. – М., 2009а. – №3. – С. 85–90.

Власкова, М. В. Речевой портрет бывшего сельского жителя : апеллятивный аспект   // Вест. Костромского ун-та им. Н. А. Некрасова. – Кострома, 2009. –  Т. 15. – № 3. – С. 54–59.

Горошко, Е. И. Особенности мужского и женского вербального поведения (психолингвистический анализ): автореф. дис. … канд. филол. наук. – М., 1996.

Гусева, М. А. Гендерные и социолингвистические характеристики языковой личности // Филол. науки. Вопросы теории и практики. – 2008. –        № 1 –2. – С. 25–30.

Гуц, Е. Н. Ненормативная лексика в речи современного городского подростка: В свете концепции языковой личности [Текст] / Е. Н. Гуц : автореф.  дисс. ... канд. филол. наук. – Омск, 1995

На вопрос о том, какие особенности речи можно контролировать, а какие нет, сложно ответить, потому что, на мой взгляд, этот вопрос нужно рассматривать в рамках научного исследования, нужно проводить психолингвистический эксперимент. На скидку могу сказать, что языковые проявления, детерминированные ментально-психологическими, гендерными характеристиками личности в устной речи, скорее всего, контролировать сложно, а вот в письменной можно, если необходимо "подделать" стиль. Есть же примеры, когда писатели-мужчины пишут книги от имени женщин. Профессия тоже влияет на речь человека, но здесь, на мой взгляд, легче контролировать свою речь, хотя профессионализмы все равно могут проскакивать. Еще зависит от умения личности переключаться с одного языкового регистра на другой. Тема очень обширная, можно рассуждать и рассуждать.

Comment: Большое спасибо!